# DRF Framework - allow User CRUD on another Users related field if they are in relationship through another model

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have a model `Application` that has fields `applicant = ForeignKey('User'...)` and `coapplicant = ForeignKey('User'...)`.

There is also a model `Income` that has field `user = ForeignKey('User'...`.

I want to allow User A to create, edit, delete `Income` objects of User B if A and B are in a relationship through `Application`.

That means:

User A can CRUD Incomes of User B and vice-versa if there is such `Application` object where `A` is an applicant and `B` co-applicant or `A` is a co-applicant and `B` applicant.

Do you know how to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can write [custom permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) something like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

class IsOwnerOrCoapplicant(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Object-level permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    Assumes the model instance has an `owner` attribute.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        if obj.user == request.user:
            return True

        # If application with both users exists return true,
        # exclude cases when applicant and coapplicant are the same just in case   
        if Application.objects.filter(applicant__in=[obj.user, request.user], coapplicant__in=[obj.user, request.user]).exclude(applicant=F('coapplicant')).exists()
           return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define a many-to-many relationship between User *A* and other Users like *B* (which I am going to call *coapplicants* from now) using the `Application` model. and [Django through fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

for example:

```py
from Django import models

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    ....
    coapplicants = models.ManyToManyField(
        'User',
        through='Application',
        through_fields=('applicant', 'coapplicant'),
    )

class Application(models.Model):
    applicant= models.ForeignKey('User',...)
    coapplicant = models.ForeignKey('User'...)
```

if you want both *A* and *B* to be in this relationship, otherwise just use one of  `applicant` or `coapplicant` in `through_fields`. [check documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

now that you defined a relationship between them, you can use **Django rest object permissions** to give User *B* access to edit `Income` objects belonging to User `A`. [documentation here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions)

```py
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrCoapplicant(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        # assuming Income instance has an attribute named `owner`.
        return obj.owner == request.user or request.user.coapplicants.filter(id=obj.owner.id).exists()
```

if you add this permission to a `ViewSet` that works with `Income` objects, `obj` argument passed to `has_object_permission` function is an `Income` instance.